# Bound on the number of people having meetings with each other

Tags: combinatorics

There is a city where live humans. Each of them choose m days, when he will visit other humans and k days, when he will invite them (these days are not intersect). And it is the fact that each of them can visit every human during these m+k days. Prove that there can be at most $\binom{m + k}{m}$ humans in the city.

Please, can you give me a hint how to start the solution?

Comment: Is it the case that on any given day, a person can either (a) go out and visit exactly one other person, (b) stay in and be visited by exactly one other person, or (c) stay home and be visited by nobody?  (Oops, clearly not, I guess.)

Comment: @BrianTung, he can make many visits, and can invite many other numans if they are free, but he can only visit or only invite

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the following is equivalent to what you mean by your question:

> There is a city where each person lives alone. Each day, each person
>   either hosts a meeting at their house, or attends a meeting at another
>   person's house. A person cannot take part in (that is, host or attend)
>   more than one meeting in a single day. In a period of $m + k$ days,
>   each person attends $m$ meetings and hosts $k$ meetings.
>
> Given that each person has- during this $m+k$ day period- attended a
>   meeting at every house in the city, prove that the city has at most
>   $\binom{m + k}{m}$ inhabitants.

The key is to realise that the number of ways of splitting the $m+k$ days into *hosting* and *attending* is $\binom{m + k}{m}$.

If the city had more than $\binom{m + k}{m}$ inhabitants, then there are more people than there are ways of choosing splitting the $m+k$ days into *hosting* and *attending*. Therefore at least two people must have chosen the same set of days to go out and attend other people's meetings, meaning that they would not attend each other's houses in that $m+k$ day period.